# HTML PHP Connecting

Tags: php, html

I was thinking if it's possible if - let's say - I have a link when clicked will go to the said page but it will actually send a value to the target page. Let's say the value is pageno.

Could i do it like

```
<a href="displaypage.html?pageno=1">
```

would that kind of thing work? I mean I want the php which would be something like this

```
<?php $pageno=$_POST['pageno']; ?>
```

and then some other process stuff. Going back, I want the php file to get the pageno that was set in the link. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be `$_GET['var']`, and yes, it is possible.

```
<a href="mypage.php?var=53">Click here</a>
```

mypage.php:

```
<?php
$var=$_GET['var'];
// ... process $var
// go to wherever
echo $var; // show the var
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_POST` superglobal variable when you send something through POST method, usually forms. If you want to get parameters in URL, use `$_GET` superglobal array.
You can use `$_REQUEST` superglobal array either for POST or GET values.

Yes, it's possible to get this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about a `GET` request where the parameters are passed into the `$_GET` array as opposed to the `$_POST` array.

```
$pageno=$_GET['pageno'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="www.mysite.com/index.php?value='.$value.'">Link</a>';
?>
```